# Online algorithm for calculating absolute deviation

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, math, statistics

I'm trying to calculate the absolute deviation of a vector [online](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm), that is, as each item in the vector is received, without using the entire vector.  The absolute deviation is the sum of the absolute difference between each item in a vector and the mean:

> [image: \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{{abs%28\overline{x}%20-%20x_i}%29}]

I know that the variance of a vector can be calculated in such a manner.  Variance is similar to absolute deviation, but each difference is squared:

> [image: \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{{%28\overline{x}%20-%20x_i}%29}^2}{n}]

The online algorithm for variance is as follows:

```
n = 0
mean = 0
M2 = 0

def calculate_online_variance(x):
    n = n + 1
    delta = x - mean
    mean = mean + delta/n
    M2 = M2 + delta*(x - mean)  # This expression uses the new value of mean
    variance_n = M2/n
    return variance_n
```

Is there such an algorithm for calculating absolute deviance? I cannot formulate a recursive definition myself, but wiser heads may prevail!

Comment: +1: Interesting online variance calculation algorithm.

Comment: Note that the online algorithm for variance given by OP is an estimation.

Comment: @Justin Peel All floating point calculations are estimations.  This algorithm is actually more accurate in many real world situations than other approaches: http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html

Answer (score 5):

As the absolute deviation between x and the mean can be defined as the square root of the squared difference, the adaptation is trivial if you are happy with a consistent but biased estimate (meaning the limit to infinity is the expected value) :

```
n = 0
mean = 0
M2 = 0

def calculate_online_avg_abs_dev(x):
    n = n + 1
    delta = x - mean
    mean = mean + delta/n
    M2 = M2 + sqrt(delta*(x - mean))  
    avg_abs_dev_n = M2/n
```

This is for the case of the average absolute deviation. Normally the mad is used (median absolute deviation), which is impossible to program recursively. but the average absolute deviation is as useful in most cases. When we're talking about hundreds of values from close-to-normal distributions, both values are very close.

If you just want the sum of the absolute devations, life is even simpler: just return M2.

Be aware of the fact that BOTH the algorithm you gave and the trivial adaptation for the absolute deviation are slightly biased.

A simulation in R to prove the algorithm works this way :

[image]

The red line is the true value, the black line is the progressive value following the algorithm outlined above.

Code :

```
calculate_online_abs_dev <- function(x,n){
  M2=0
  mean=0
  out <- numeric(n)
  for(i in 1:n) {
      delta <- x[i] - mean
      mean <- mean + delta/i
      M2 = M2 + sqrt(delta*(x[i] - mean))
      out[i] <- M2/i

  }
  return(out)
}

set.seed(2010)
x <- rnorm(100)

Abs_Dev <- calculate_online_abs_dev(x,length(x))
True_Val <- sapply(1:length(x),function(i)sum(abs(x[1:i]-mean(x[1:i])))/i)

plot(1:length(x),Abs_Dev,type="l",xlab="number of values",lwd=2)
lines(1:length(x),True_Val,col="red",lty=2,lwd=2)
legend("bottomright",lty=c(1,2),col=c("black","red"),
  legend=c("Online Calc","True Value"))
```

Comment: I was hoping that someone might be able to derive something more sophisticated that would minimize the error associated with the dreaded `sqrt`, but it looks like this is the best we can get...

Comment: @fmark : If you can minimize the error associated with the dreaded sqrt more than what I show you in my simulation, you'll have to be exact up to 6 digits and more. With n>100, the differences are neglectable. And frankly, your variance algorithm is about as exact as this one, which is easily shown in a similar simulation. Sometimes you shouldn't look too far. The law of big numbers guarantees this solution will converge to the true value, and rather fast even.

Comment: > The Law of Big Numbers
You should not use a normal distribution for testing - the law of big numbers only applies to normal distributions!
I tried more biased input, e.g. (Python) `series = [random.randint(50, 70) for i in range(33)] + [random.randint(40, 50) for i in range(66)]`
and got the following graph in `R` which is continuing to diverge from the true value:
[Output of biased input in R](http://imgur.com/SePtfhv)

Comment: The Law of big numbers assures that the distribution of the statistic (not the original data) is normal in asymptopia. If you extend your analysis to 1000 values, you'll see both converge. The more your original distribution deviates from normality, the longer it takes for the law of big numbers to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.

In the formula for variance it is possible to separate the x and x<sup>2</sup> terms, so that it suffices to keep track of those sums (and n). In the formula for absolute deviation this is not possible.

I think the best one can do (apart from keeping the whole vector and calculating the absolute deviation on demand) is keep a sorted list of elements. This is O(log(n)) for each new element, but after you add an element the cost of recalculating the absolute deviation is O(log(n)). This may or may not be worthwhile, depending on your application.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your sorted list algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

The formula for variance that you give is ONE of the many that are possible (I can think of three distinct ways to do that computation) although I have not verified that yours is correct. It looks reasonably close to what I recall.

The problem is that absolute value is actually more "nonlinear" in a sense than is the sum of  squares of the deviations. This prevents you from being able to do that calculation in a recursive form in a loop, at least not without retaining all of the previous values of x. You must compute the overall mean in advance for that sum.

Edit: I see that beta agrees with me. IF you saved all of the previous data points, in a sorted list, you could then efficiently compute the updated desired deviation. But this is counter to the spirit of your request.

Comment: +1 I was hoping this is not the case.  Using Joris' adaptation will have to suffice then!